# How to color rows based on two cell values in Open/Libre Office?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, conditional-formatting

I am trying to apply conditional formatting to an entire row based on two cell values. The style is to be applied only if both cells have a particular value. I tried applying formula of the form:

```
$A1="Value1" & $B1="Value2"
```

But it does not apply the style. How to solve this in Libre Office?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [**`AND()`**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Logical_Functions#AND) function to combine the two conditions:

1. First, use "`Formula is...`" as criteria;
2. then enter

   > `AND($A1="Value"; $B1="Value")`

[image]

Depending on your local settings, in that formula, you may have to replace the semicolon `;` by a comma `,`.